# Pure Javascript- Change class of onclick element generated by function

Tags: javascript, onclick, this

I'm new in coding and have been around a problem for a few days but found no solution.
I'm trying to build a canvas with a grid made out of squares and, when a square is clicked, it changes its background color.
I'm learning pure javascript and my problem is that I can't find a way to refer to the clicked element and change only its class, because my grid is generated by a function. I am doing it this way because I want to be able to change the canvas size in future.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Square Canvas Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="javascript:setInitialCanvas()">
    <header>
        <h1>Square artist</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="gameInterfaceContainer">
        <button id="clearCanvas" onclick="clearAllSquares()">Clear All</button>
    
        <div id="canvas">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function setInitialCanvas(){
    for (let i =0; i<400; i++){
        let initialSquare = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(initialSquare);
        initialSquare.className = "canvasSquare clearSquare";
        initialSquare.onclick = changeSquareColor(this);
        initialSquare.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        initialSquare.id = "square" + i;
    }
}
function changeSquareColor(this){
    let squareColor = ["white","blue","black","green","red","yellow","gray","brown"];
    let colorIndex = 0;

    while (squareColor[colorIndex] != this.style.backgroundColor){
        colorIndex += 1;
    }
    if(this.style.backgroundColor == squareColor[squareColor.length]){
        this.style.backgroundColor = squareColor[0];
    }else
    colorIndex += 1;
    this.style.backgroundColor = squareColor[colorIndex];

}
```

Thank you!

*Edit: Adding codepen (that doesn't work) https://codepen.io/ccue92/pen/qBNKLQY

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example here? https://codepen.io/

Comment: https://codepen.io/ccue92/pen/qBNKLQY. Now it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: setInitialCanvas is not defined
    at onload (index.html:10)" and can't understand why. I'm so lost right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is you're not binding the changeSquareColor function to onclick event, you are binding the result of it.

You need to change onclick binding like this:

```
initialSquare.onclick = function(event) {
    changeSquareColor(event.target);
}
```

And do not use "this" as a variable name, because it's a reserved word for the current scope:

```
function changeSquareColor(square) {
    let squareColor = ["white","blue","black","green","red","yellow","gray","brown"];
    let colorIndex = 0;

    while (squareColor[colorIndex] != square.style.backgroundColor){
        colorIndex += 1;
    }
    if(square.style.backgroundColor == squareColor[squareColor.length]){
        square.style.backgroundColor = squareColor[0];
    } else {
        colorIndex += 1;
    }
    square.style.backgroundColor = squareColor[colorIndex];
}
```